# Ldap access to local adfs

Tags: active-directory, gitlab-ce

Let me first explain my adfs setup.

```
Domain: my-example.com
       -- test-user1
       --(OU) company user
           --(OU) Network
               -- test-user2
```

So, when i try to access test-user1 by giving cn=my-domain,cn=com, it fails.
Also, i would like to access test-user2.
And it would be really helpful if anyone could explain what this CN parameter is?
I am trying to setup gitlab with my ADFS.
Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: It appears you're not clear on the difference between AD and ADFS.  AD - which is, strictly, AD DS, nowadays, is Active Directory Domain Services - that's what you've drawn a diagram of, above. AD DS is Microsoft's directory services system and implements the LDAP standard.  ADFS is Active Directory Federation Services which is Microsoft's SAML/WS-Federation implementation.  CN is Common Name.  I suggest you start with an article like this: [Understanding Active Directory Services](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=101405&seqNum=7)

Comment: Thanks. Now, atleast, i have some starting point.